# Add Windows command line parameters automatically when using Wine

Tags: linux, wine

I have a program that I need to specify the parameter to run it. For example,

```
wine program.exe -parameter
```

This means that I need to open a terminal window to run the program, instead of simply clicking on it.

How can I make this specific program `program.exe` be run with parameter `-parameter` automatically (by just clicking on it)?

Comment: .desktop files can pass arguments. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/86787/how-to-pass-file-as-argument-in-desktop-file-for-wine-application

Comment: That is a good workaround, but this doesn't work for `program.exe` per se, only for `program.desktop` file associated with it.